# Ranges within ArrayFormula in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

Is it possible to include ranges of ranges in arrayformulas in Google Sheets?

For instance, the normal formula is:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:C1)
```

This joins the cells in range A1:C1 with a space

However, I want this to repeat over the entire column, so something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,(A1:A):(C1:C)))
```

Is this possible in google sheets?

Comment: For documentation purposes, please accept the answer if it helped you or give your input regarding the answer.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:E);;9^9)))
```

[image]

---

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:E);;9^9)))
```

[image]

---

to skip empty cells do:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:E);;9^9))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
=arrayformula(A1:A & " " & B1:B & " " & C1:C)
```

[image: explanation]